# How can I iterate through a 2D Seq in scala using the foreach function?

Tags: scala, 2d, seq

I've been trying to iterate through a 2d Seq using foreach but I haven't been successful even though I googled a lot, I couldn't find anything about it(at least in scala). Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so others can help you better. Also consider adding the input you have and the output you expect to have.

Comment: `my2dSeq.foreach(_.foreach(x => . . . ))`

Answer (score 1):

If you got something like

```
@ Seq(Seq(1,2,3), Seq(4,5,6), Seq(7,8,9)) 
res0: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
```

You got two options, either iterate twice:

```
res0.foreach { row =>
  row.foreach { cell =>
    pprint.pprintln(cell)
  }
}
```

Or lose some information and `flatten` the `Seq[Seq[_]]` into a `Seq[_]`:

```
res0.flatten.foreach { cell =>
  pprint.pprintln(cell)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant help, How can I loop through the indexes of the elements using foreach for 2d Seq?